# windows 11 podman compose Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: podman, podman-compose

I have installed podman desktop 4.9.2 in windows 11. Also installed componse extension in podman.

When I tried running bellow commands, getting error as follow:

**Commands:**

```
docker-compose -f new-kafka-zookeeper-kafkaui.yaml up -d
podman compose --file .\new-kafka-zookeeper-kafkaui.yaml up --detach
```

**Error:**

```
Error response from daemon: {"message":"lookup registry-1.docker.io: Temporary failure in name resolution"}
Error: executing C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\docker-compose.exe --file .\new-kafka-zookeeper-kafkaui.yaml up --detach: exit status 18
```

Please help me in running docker compose on windows 11 without docker desktop. Also please suggest tools other than podman or docker desktop if any.